# How to plot function with evenly spaced x values in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plotting

I'm trying to plot this function

```
func=exp(x-sqrt(2))-cos(x-sqrt(2))-(x-sqrt(2))
```

in Matlab using 101 evenly spaced x values. If I just say

```
fplot(fun, [-1 3], 'o')
```

the graph is the correct shape but the actual values of the points are determined by Matlab to give the best shape of the graph. I want to tell it exactly where to put the points, 101 evenly spaced between -1 and 3.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `linspace` function,

```
x=linspace(-1,3,101);
func=exp(x-sqrt(2))-cos(x-sqrt(2))-(x-sqrt(2));
plot(x,func,'or');
```

Comment: Note that this also uses a different plot command: `fplot` wants as its first argument a string or a function handle, `plot` a vector. This will probably be confusing.

Comment: Thanks guys, this worked. I had tried doing this with fplot and it wasn't working correctly, so this is much better!